# How to make ssh remember unlocked ssh-keys not in default directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, passphrase

I structured my private/public-keys in a subfolder of ".ssh" called "keys".
Mapping is done by a .ssh/config file.
Now I have to retype the passphrase for every key every time I use it.

Before this change, the unlocked key was remembered automatically on demand as default behaviour (OS: Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`keychain`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/keychain), a simple [`ssh-agent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) wrapper, to handle this for you.

Add to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
eval $(keychain --clear --eval id_rsa id_dsa id_ecdsa other.id_rsa )
```

This way you only need to type your passphrases once upon login. You can still manually add and list keys directly using the agent as usual:

```
$ ssh-add -l
4096 10:93:fe:6c:2b:36:xx:be:78:xx:bd:xx:b7:f9:0f:46 /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
1024 86:dc:ed:e0:c8:f4:99:bc:99:ee:55:xx:ac:51:e6:cb /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa (DSA)
521 28:xx:f4:d6:10:xx:40:4b:cd:xx:ef:e2:fc:8f:0b:xx /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa (ECDSA)
4096 5d:5a:xx:41:xx:2e:ab:ae:xx:ff:5c:47:xx:3a:cf:xx /home/user/.ssh/other.id_rsa (RSA)
```

The `--eval` argument in `keychain(1)` accepts full paths, so you can have your keys wherever you want to.

Comment: Isn't this solution more or less equivalent to adding keys manually in the bashrc via `ssh-add`? The desired behaviour is that the passphrase is requested when the key is required (**on demand**) and stored for following tasks.

Comment: `keychain` is an **ssh-agent wrapper** as noted above, so it is a convenient way to not have to use `ssh-agent` directly. Advantages are having an `ssh-agent` (and a `gpg-agent` if there's the need) handled for you. You can start with some keys automatically added at login, and add the rest on demand using `ssh-add`. This solution, coupled with a `~/.ssh/config` file specifying which keys to user per host/user is what I've found more comfortable to use.